# SMS service in PB9

Tags: sms, powerbuilder

Good Day.

I'm using Pb9 and want to know if it's possible to send sms's from my application? 
I found a related article in this forum for pb11.5 but it's not helping me much.

If it's possible - then could someone post some sample code.

Thanks in advance.
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I use with our SMS provider - Clickatell.

public function boolean wf_sendsms (string as_phonenbr, string as_message);// send sms message

OLEObject objHTTP
 
String ls_API, ls_User, ls_Pass, ls_From
String ls_URL, ls_Response

ls_API  = "?????"
ls_User = "?????"
ls_Pass = "?????"
ls_From = "18887776666"

objHTTP = Create OLEObject

If objHTTP.ConnectToNewObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") < 0 Then
    Return False
End If

ls_URL  = "http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?"
ls_URL += "api_id=" + ls_API + "&user=" + ls_User
ls_URL += "&password=" + ls_Pass + "&from=" + ls_From
ls_URL += "&to=1" + as_phonenbr + "&mo=1" + "&text=" + as_message

objHTTP.Open("POST", ls_URL, False)
objHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")
objHTTP.Send()

ls_Response = objHTTP.responseText

mle_result.Text = ls_Response

objHTTP.DisconnectObject()

Destroy objHTTP

Return True

end function

Comment: Hi. First time getting back to this after my initial post.
I've implemented the code but get a 'Error calling external function open .... ' when running it..
objHTTP.ConnectToNewObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") returns 0 i.e. success.
Any clues pls.
Thanks in advance
Alex